# Trying to get started with winsock in C, how to keep connected?

Tags: c, winsock2

I'm a beginner and trying to set up a TCP-client for the first time, using winsock. I put together a minimal  client using some bits of code I found in examples (see below). It's basically working, i.e. I can receive the server's messages, and sending messages gives the expected results.

However, unless I add a loop which constantly does a receive/send routine (or even just the receive part) the connection is closed immediately after it has been established. Can I do something to keep the connection open and only receive or send something when there is demand for it?

The server is a closed source piece of software, so I have no idea about how it is set up.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int startWinsock(void) {
    WSADATA wsa;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
}

int main(void) {
    long rc;
    SOCKET s;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;

    printf("Starting Winsock... ");

    rc = startWinsock();

    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("Error: unable to start Winsock, error code: %d\n", rc);
    }
    else {
        printf("done.\n");
    }

    printf("Creating socket... ");

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error: Unable to create socket, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else {
        printf("done.\n");
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(10134);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    rc = connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR));

    if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Connection failed, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else {
        printf("Connected to 127.0.0.1.\n");
    }
    

    //if I add a loop here, which receives and/or sends stuff constantly, the connection stays established


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless there's an error somewhere, TCP connections stay connected until they are actively closed. Program termination (when you do `exit` or the `main` function returns) does an active close on the connection.

Comment: Thank you! So as long as my program is running, even if it is doing other (not socket-related) stuff in the meantime, the client should stay connected? That's the bit of info I was missing!

Comment: The server may close the connection for whatever reason, such as time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

1. Your client tries to connect to the server.
2. If it succeeds, send a command, and read the response.
3. Keep receiving and sending until you're "done", then close the socket.

In other words:

- You have control over when to close the connection - the socket will stay open until you close it.
- Essentially, you're inventing your own custom [network protocol](https://medium.com/@nikolaystoykov/build-custom-protocol-on-top-of-tcp-with-node-js-part-1-fda507d5a262)

STRONG SUGGESTION:

Review [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Comment: Thank you (can't upvote yet)! I am working through Beej's guide, but as a beginner many things aren't as obvious as they probably should be :-)

So in essence, the connection will be kept up until I either close it actively (as mentioned above) or my program terminates? Then of course that is the reason why the client disconnects instanty with the code sample above, because it's just doing nothing more atm.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  SUGGESTION: Google for other (shorter) tutorials and/or code.  For example: https://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html